# geocoder gives wrong address in ios 5

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, core-location

For 5.0, i use the clgeocoder and clplacemark, but i get "1 stockton street" everytime. I believe 1 stockton st is the address of an apple store in s.f. The Mk classes work for the same program for younger version simulators.

Why is the 5.0 simulator defaulting to the store's location?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Location Simulation section](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_2.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/00200-SW11) in the release notes for Xcode 4.2

You can also simulate movement using a GPX file, check this out [Simulate Location including movement in Xcode 4.2 / iOS5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905054/simulate-location-including-movement-in-xcode-4-2-ios5)

Answer (score 0):

Earlier versions of iOS simulator have no location while iOS 5 Simulator have the ability to simulate location (note the location arrow at the bottom of xCode screen). I don't know how you simulate location changes in your code, but it may happen, that simulator activity interrupts your location changes chain.