# How can I simulate iPhone moving, with specific speed? Using gpx file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cllocationmanager

I would like test on **simulator**, that a function is trigered, if the iPhone reaces specific speed. So the question is how can I simulate iPhone moving, with specific speed? Using gpx file?

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
    double gpsSpeed = newLocation.speed;
    if (gpsSpeed > 30) {
        //myLogic
        [SomeClass function];
    }
}
```

Comment: question may have been answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802156/testing-corelocation-on-iphone-simulator

Comment: Look here, you need to use Automation tool from Instruments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439495/when-using-gpx-in-xcode-to-simulate-location-changes-is-there-a-way-to-control/11709258#11709258

Comment: Please put that as a answer so I could mark it is as correct

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
  - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
        double gpsSpeed = 31;
        if (gpsSpeed > 30) {
            //myLogic
            [SomeClass function];
        }
    }
```

The simulator can't generate `CLLocation` objects for you. You can generate them yourself, but you'd essentially be doing the same thing as just telling the if statement to execute.

Comment: you made me smile :))) I need to test the whole thing

Comment: The best solution is probably to add a button or other control that you can access that calls `[SomeClass function]`. Then you can run the app normally and simulate `gpsSpeed > 30` whenever you need to. You probably won't find a better solution for the simulator; I'm working on an app that includes core location right now and I just keep it running on my phone.

Comment: I was told it should be done with a gpx file. I thought somebody could help me understand it