# GPX track doesn't work in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, gpx

I'm working on iOS app which uses GPS and I want to test GPS in the Xcode Simulator. But when I load GPX file with track, it doesn't work at all (true for testing on real device too). Is there any way to reproduce mock walking in the Xcode?

Part of my GPX file:

```
<trk>
<name>GPSTestV2</name>
<trkseg>
  <trkpt lat="50.38836970" lon="30.48965690">
    <ele>165.00000</ele>
    <time>2010-01-01T00:00:00Z</time>
  </trkpt>
  <trkpt lat="50.38836280" lon="30.48971590">
    <ele>165.00000</ele>
    <time>2010-01-01T00:00:01Z</time>
  </trkpt>
  <trkpt lat="50.38835600" lon="30.48976950">
    <ele>164.00000</ele>
    <time>2010-01-01T00:00:02Z</time>
  </trkpt>
  ...
</trkseg>
```

Comment: The code generated at https://gpxgenerator.com works perfect in XCode!

Comment: Perhaps you can try GPSBabel, I have posted an answer in another question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43428073/gpx-file-does-not-load-ios-xcode/44383838#44383838. Hope it can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that this format in unacceptable for Xcode (but it works perfectly on Android, lol).

**Right format for Xcode**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36416589/5424739