# Simulate Location Updates on Xcode8 (Instruments/Automation not available anymore)

Tags: ios, xcode, location, instruments, simulate

I need to test an app on location updates. The app has to detect things like if the user is moving or static, speed and significant location updates.

Ideally I would like to simulate a path on Xcode Simulator and read on the debugger how the app is reacting to that. I added a GPX file with multiple locations but there is no way to set a delay between the different locations.

I found [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439495/when-using-gpx-in-xcode-to-simulate-location-changes-is-there-a-way-to-control) that solved the problem using Instruments/Automation, but that is not possible anymore on Xcode8 because [Apple took away the Automation tool from Instruments](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/60604).

What would be the best way to do it?
Thanks