# App Crashes When Background Location Received

Tags: ios, swift, crash, cllocationmanager

I am trying to send the location update to the server in the background

App **sometimes** crashes in the background

Here is my `locationmanager delegate`

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

            if let lat = manager.location?.coordinate.latitude,
                let long = manager.location?.coordinate.longitude {
                glat = String(lat)
                glong = String(long)

                if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .background {
                self.updatebackloc(lat, long: long)
                }

                if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active {
                self.updateloc(lat, long: long)
                    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
                    let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
                    if (status == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedAlways) {
                    locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
                    }
                }
            }
            }
```

This is the updatebacklog function

```
func updatebackloc(_ lat: CLLocationDegrees, long: CLLocationDegrees) {
        let userID = TegKeychain.get("userID")!
        let parameters: Parameters = ["userID": userID, "lat": lat, "long":long]
        Alamofire.request("https://xxxxx.com/ios/updatebackloc.php", method: .post, parameters: parameters).validate().responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                if let json = response.result.value {
                    var success = 0
                    if let dictJSON = json as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        if let successInteger = dictJSON["success"] as? Int {
                            success = successInteger
                            if success == 1
                            {

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            case .failure(_):
                return
            }
        }
    }
```

`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` part

```
if let _ = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.location] {
                    startSignificationLocation()
                }
```

`startSignificationLocation` function triggered on `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
func startSignificationLocation() {
        let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
    }
```

Here is the crash log

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0                          0x10285b798 specialized AppDelegate.updatebackloc(Double, long : Double) -> () + 4339644312
1                          0x10285b8e4 specialized AppDelegate.locationManager(CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations : [CLLocation]) -> () (AppDelegate.swift:396)
2                          0x1028540c0 @objc AppDelegate.locationManager(CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations : [CLLocation]) -> () (AppDelegate.swift)
3  CoreLocation                   0x1874f97bc (null) + 77412
4  CoreLocation                   0x1874f901c (null) + 75460
5  CoreLocation                   0x1874e16b4 (null) + 1004
6  CoreFoundation                 0x180ea3590 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 20
7  CoreFoundation                 0x180ea2e60 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 288
8  CoreFoundation                 0x180ea10c8 __CFRunLoopRun + 2436
9  CoreFoundation                 0x180dc0c58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
10 GraphicsServices               0x182c6cf84 GSEventRunModal + 100
11 UIKit                          0x18a5195c4 UIApplicationMain + 236
12                         0x1027fe524 main (InboxInterests.swift:30)
13 libdyld.dylib                  0x1808e056c start + 4
```

[image]

Here is the code

[image]

code as text

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        if let lat = manager.location?.coordinate.latitude,
            let long = manager.location?.coordinate.longitude {
            glat = String(lat)
            glong = String(long)

            if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .background {
            self.updatebackloc(lat, long: long)
            }

            if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active {
            self.updateloc(lat, long: long)
                locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
                let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
                if (status == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedAlways) {
                locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
                }
            }
        }
        }

        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
            print(error)
        }


        func updateloc(_ lat: CLLocationDegrees, long: CLLocationDegrees) {
            let userID = TegKeychain.get("userID")!
            let parameters: Parameters = ["userID": userID, "lat": lat, "long":long]
            Alamofire.request("https://xxxxx.com/ios/updateloc.php", method: .post, parameters: parameters).validate().responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    if let json = response.result.value {
                        var success = 0
                        if let dictJSON = json as? [String: AnyObject] {
                            if let successInteger = dictJSON["success"] as? Int {
                                success = successInteger
                                if success == 1
                                {

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                case .failure(_):
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    func updatebackloc(_ lat: CLLocationDegrees, long: CLLocationDegrees) {
        guard let userID = TegKeychain.get("userID") else {
            return
        }
        let parameters: Parameters = ["userID": userID, "lat": lat, "long":long]
        Alamofire.request("https://xxxxx.com/ios/updatebackloc.php", method: .post, parameters: parameters).validate().responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                if let json = response.result.value {
                    var success = 0
                    if let dictJSON = json as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        if let successInteger = dictJSON["success"] as? Int {
                            success = successInteger
                            if success == 1
                            {

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            case .failure(_):
                return
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you locate the position where the crash happens? Which statement throw out the exception?

Comment: The line of code throwing the exception would be helpful.

Comment: Does it crash only if the device is locked?

Comment: @shallowThought it crashes in the background

Comment: "AppDelegate.swift:436"  Which is line 436 in the code you posted?

Comment: @PhillipMills did you mean 396?

Comment: No.  "1 Jemiyet 0x100e20824 AppDelegate.updatebackloc(Double, long : Double) -> () (AppDelegate.swift:436)"

Comment: @PhillipMills I edited the question with the new crash log. I changed some code so lines changed. It says now 396 which is self.updatebackloc(lat, long: long) calling the function I wrote in the question.

Comment: Please confirm: it works sometimes and sometimes crashes using the same user ID.

Comment: @shallowThought Yes I confirm

Comment: @UtkuDalmaz have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: @KaraBenNemsi will try very soon

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your background location calls inside a UIBackgroundTask.

```
var bgTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier?
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.

    bgTask = application.beginBackgroundTask(withName: "bgLocation", expirationHandler: {
        if let task = self.bgTask {
            application.endBackgroundTask(task)
            self.bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
        }
    })
}
```

Then when calling your updatebackloc function use the proper background queue and end the background task.

Something like:

```
func updatebackloc(_ lat: CLLocationDegrees, long: CLLocationDegrees) {
    let userID = TegKeychain.get("userID")!
    let parameters: Parameters = ["userID": userID, "lat": lat, "long":long]
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        Alamofire.request("https://xxxxx.com/ios/updatebackloc.php", method: .post, parameters: parameters).validate().responseJSON { response in

            //response handling here...
            //....
            if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
                if let task = appDelegate.bgTask {
                    UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(task)
                    appDelegate.bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting Ambiguous reference to member 'application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)' error when I try to end the bgtask with application.endBackgroundTask(task) code

Comment: @UtkuDalmaz you're calling this from outside AppDelegate right? see my updated code

Comment: applicationDidEnterBackground is the wrong place to start the task. It will be killed latestly after 3 minutes. SignificantLocationChages can wakeup your app at any time later.

Answer (score 10):

I highly suspect you are trying to force-unwrap a `nil` value in this line:

```
let userID = TegKeychain.get("userID")!
```

To figure out if I am correct, try if this fixes the crash (but still does not do what you want obviously):

```
guard let userID = TegKeychain.get("userID") else {
    return
}
```

Assuming `TegKeychain.get("userID")` is trying to get a value for a key from the system KeyChain, this value has most probably been written to the KeyChain with a non-suitable accessibility. Thus you are not allowed to access it in background and `nil` is returned.

To fix this, set a value that fits your needs for key `kSecAttrAccessible` when saving the credential to the KeyChain.

[kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/ksecattraccessibleafterfirstunlock) is recommended by Apple and probably fits your needs.

In code:

```
let userIdToSave = "secretString"
guard let secretAsData = userIdToSave.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) else {
    return
}
let keyChainKey = "userID"
let query = [
    kSecClass as String: kSecClassGenericPassword as String,
    kSecAttrAccessible as String: kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock as String,
    kSecAttrService as String: yourService,
    kSecAttrAccount as String: keyChainKey,
    kSecValueData as String: secretAsData] as [String : Any]

SecItemDelete(query as CFDictionary)

let status = SecItemAdd(query as CFDictionary, nil)
```

For details check [Apples Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/ksecattraccessible).

---

**Edit:**

According to your statements in the comments my guess was wrong.

My next guess is that the OS is killing you in the middle of the network process. You can avoid that by asking the OS for more time.

To do so, start a backgroundTask.

In code that would look something like this:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    var bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        if let _ = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.location] {
            // app is launched in backgrond due to location change
            bgTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: { // Start background task
                UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(bgTask)
                bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
            })
            startSignificationLocation()
        }
        return true
    }

    // ... your other methods

    func updatebackloc(_ lat: CLLocationDegrees, long: CLLocationDegrees) {
        guard let userID = TegKeychain.get("userID") else {
            return
        }
        let parameters: Parameters = ["userID": userID, "lat": lat, "long":long]
        Alamofire.request("https://xxxxx.com/ios/updatebackloc.php", method: .post, parameters: parameters).validate().responseJSON { response in
            defer {
                // Tell the OS that you are done
                UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(bgTask)
                bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
            }
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                if let json = response.result.value {
                    var success = 0
                    if let dictJSON = json as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        if let successInteger = dictJSON["success"] as? Int {
                            success = successInteger
                            if success == 1
                            {

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            case .failure(_):
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also do not forget to setup required Capatibilities as mentions in other answers:

[image]

You also should do more debugging. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26799703/1457385) about how to simulate movement in Xcode.

Comment: What should kSecAttrService be?

Comment: I am still having the problem

Comment: We need more information. How I understand: It does not crash using the `guard` statement. In other words, unwrapping `nil` is the root of the issue. Please confirm.

Comment: It crashed also using the guard statement

Comment: If so please note: if the value for a given `userID` has been written before with a non-suitable accessibility, you have to use [SecItemUpdate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1393617-secitemupdate?language=objc) instead of `SecItemAdd` to set the `kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock` for the given `UserId`.

Comment: Please let us know which exact line crashes within updateLoc and post the currently used code.

Comment: I edited the question with the exact code screenshot

Comment: Please post code, not screenshots. Also the code does not use `guard`.

Comment: Thank you but @ahbou posted the solution before you so I gotta choose his answer.

Comment: No problem and yu are welcome. (ahbou's solution will still crash when you app is woken up due to location changes though)

Comment: If that happens I will try your solution and choose your answer. Best

Comment: You probably have to combine then. Start background task when going into background AND when getting started

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need to configure an Alamofire Session Manager with the background configuration in order to perform a request in the background. Then in order to make the request use the properly configured session manager.

e.g.

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "com.example.app.background")
let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
```

Comment: Thanks. I will be trying this one.

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled the location services for background modes? If yes then try to reinitialise location manager when you enter background it actually worked for me but the best practise is to save the coordinates in data-base whenever user became active sync unsynced records to the server.   [image]

Comment: Yes I have it enabled